# Many to Many Relationship in a Transactional System With Google Datastore/Python NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

I am writting an application for a crop warehousing company, which purchases the harvested crop and stores it in one or more warehouses. Till now limitations of Google App Engine/Datastore was not posing problem to me. And I so deep into the project that it's very difficult to return.

I have to establish a many to many relationship between two *Kinds* which are transactional (means parent/ancestor queries) in nature. I am not sure what is the right approach to do this. This is the business logic:

1. Warehouse issues a purchase order for a specific quantity (PO). So we create an entity in *PO Kind* for each purchase order (PO).
2. Goods are received at the warehouse. So we create an entity in *GRN Kind*. (GRN=Goods Receiving Notes).

Here is many to many relationship.

3. One GRN may be required to complete one PO.
4. One GRN may be required to complete many POs.
5. Many GRNs may be required to complete one PO.
6. Many GRNs may be required to complete many POs.

This is a relevent snapshot of the code.

```
class Warehouse(ndb.Models):
    name = ndb.TextProperty()
    capacity = ndb.FloatProperty()
    current_stock = ndb.FloatProperty()

class PurchaseOrder(ndb.Models):
    quantity = ndb.FloatProperty()
    remaining = ndb.FloatProperty()
    is_complete = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    grn = ndb.KeyProprty(repeated=True, kind=GRN)

class GRN(ndb.Models):
    quantity = ndb.FloatProperty()
    remaining = ndb.FloatProperty()
    is_complete = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    po = ndb.KeyProprty(repeated=True, kind=PurchaseOrder)
```

## Entity Group Relationships

Warehouse -> GRN

Warehouse -> PO

To establish many - to - many relationship I hold all the related GRN Keys in a PO record and all related PO Keys in a GRN record. This is working fine for me.

But in case I have to edit a GRN or PO in the back date, then I am not able to handle the complication of cascaded changes which may impact other GRNs and POs.

- Somewhere I read I should be using a third model to hold the many - to - many relationship, rather than storing the related keys. I am not able to visualize what that third table to should contain. *

I know my problem is very specific and I have not funished all the details. But just help me with the right approach for this kind of problem pattern. I will handle the rest. Or provide any link if this is already documented somewhere.

Comment: Is it like you should keep properties like quantity in sync between PO and GRN or what?

Comment: Yes, both needs to be balanced on weight.

Comment: Suppose a PO is made of 100 KG, then it can linked to 5 GRN instances of 20KG each. A PO and GRN are considered complete only when the many-to-many relationship between them is balanced by weight.

Comment: So, looks like each related GRN and PO belongs to one entity group, why not to use ComputedProperty with fetching all related entities and checking for weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a many-to-many relationship called `GRNinstance` that links a single GRN instance with a single PO:

```
class PurchaseOrder(ndb.Models):
    quantity = ndb.FloatProperty()
    remaining = ndb.FloatProperty()
    is_complete = ndb.BooleanProperty()

class GRN(ndb.Models):
    quantity = ndb.FloatProperty()
    remaining = ndb.FloatProperty()
    is_complete = ndb.BooleanProperty()

class GRNinstance(ndb.Models):
    po = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=PurchaseOrder)
    grn = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=GRN)
    quantity = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

The sum of `GRNinstance.quantity` for a particular `po` should add up to `PurchaseOrder.quantity`, and the sum of `GRNinstance.quantity` for a particular `grn` should add up to `GRN.quantity`.

In fact, Dmitry's `ComputedProperty` could replace both `PurchaseOrder.quantity` and `GRN.quantity` (but that could be slow).  Maybe `is_complete` could be a simple test:

```
is_complete = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.remaining > 0)
```

Comment: fabulous! in fact I took a similar approach, using a third table to establish relationship between the two Kinds. Thanks a lot, your answer has given me the confidence that I am on right track.